# How to retrieve the elements of lists named a1 a2 a3 in for loop?

Tags: bash

I try to make this (example...) :

```
list1 = ("one" "two" "three")
list2 = ("four" "five" "six")
list3 = ("seven" "eight" "nine")
listn (finite number)...

for i in {1..n}; do
    list= ${list[$i][@]}
    echo "The elements of list $i are : $list"
done
```

but

```
${list[$i][@]}
```

is wrong ("substitution" error).

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For help with a code problem here, we require a [mre], which means the code needs to replicate the problem you're describing. This code does not; it has a syntax error on line 1. Please [edit] to fix it. For more tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, `{1..n}` doesn't do brace expansion, and `list= ${...}` should be `list=${...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot have spaces around the equal sign in variable assignments.

The "classical" sh answer would be to use `eval`, however bash has the the notion of 'nameref' variables for variable indirection. They are be declared with `declare -n` like so:

```
list1=("one" "two" "three")
list2=("four" "five" "six")
list3=("seven" "eight" "nine")

for i in {1..3}; do
    declare -n varptr=list$i
    list=${varptr[@]}
    echo "The elements of list $i are : $list"
done
```

Output:

```
$ bash /tmp/x.sh
The elements of list 1 are : one two three
The elements of list 2 are : four five six
The elements of list 3 are : seven eight nine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` for double substitution in `bash`. In the first pass only inner variable is substituted and `\$` is not used for substitution but replaced with `$` and it is used for substitution in the second pass. Sample code is:

```
#! /bin/bash

list1=("one" "two" "three")
list2=("four" "five" "six")
list3=("seven" "eight" "nine")

for i in {1..3}; do
    list=$(eval echo \${list$i[@]})
    echo "The elements of list $i are : $list"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Özgür Murat Sağdıçoğlu for your help !!

Comment: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead#:~:text=There%20are%20many%20shell%20constructs,how%20it%20could%20be%20exploited.)